# Making a Dictionary from a Dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, iteration

I'm a beginner in python and I am having a tough time making a dictionary from a dictionary. I have a dictionary am wondering how to make another dictionary from that dictionary with the average price per food type. The dictionary looks like this:

```
food = {
    1: ['Pasta Primavera', 'Italian', 1000,  8.50],
    2: ['Pizza Margarita', 'Italian', 1200, 7.50],
    3: ['Hamburger', 'American', 1100,  5.50],
    4: ['Milkshake', 'American', 700, 3.00],
    5: ['Bruscetta', 'Italian', 500, 6.00],
    6: ['Sauerkraut', 'German', 300,  4.00 ],
    7: ['Sausage', 'German' , 500, 7.00],
    8: ['Apfelstrudel', 'German', 750, 4.50],
    9: ['Sauerbraten', 'German', 950, 10.00],
}
```

The last value is the price, and the food type is index 1. And I'm Looking for an output like this:

```
newdict = {'Italian':7.33, 'American':4.25, 'German': 6.375 }
```

or something like:

```
newdict = {'Italian':[Average:7.33], 'American':[Average:4.25], 'German':[Average: 6.375]}
```

I'm assuming you can use a loop to make this possible.

**Edit: I know this is not a code writing service. I'm sorry for asking for help. I would delete this post if I could.**

Comment: Look into `itertools.groupby`.

Comment: Hey Dack, please read this: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: You should make an honest attempt to solve this yourself and put your code into the question. StackOverflow isn’t a code-writing service.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Taking a back to basics, vanilla python, approach:

We start by converting the current data into a list:

```py
In [137]: food.values()
Out[137]: 
[['Pasta Primavera', 'Italian', 1000, 8.5],
 ['Pizza Margarita', 'Italian', 1200, 7.5],
 ['Hamburger', 'American', 1100, 5.5],
 ['Milkshake', 'American', 700, 3.0],
 ['Bruscetta', 'Italian', 500, 6.0],
 ['Sauerkraut', 'German', 300, 4.0],
 ['Sausage', 'German', 500, 7.0],
 ['Apfelstrudel', 'German', 750, 4.5],
 ['Sauerbraten', 'German', 950, 10.0]]
```

Now we can loop over each element add the information we want to a dictionary:

```py
all_data = {}

for i in food.values():
   try:    
      # add price (last element) to a list of all items in country (i[1])
      all_data[i[1]].append(i[-1])
   except KeyError:
      # if we dont have this country yet, create it
      all_data[i[1]] = [i[-1]]
```

This gives us :

```py
In [144]: all_data
Out[144]: 
{'American': [5.5, 3.0],
 'German': [4.0, 7.0, 4.5, 10.0],
 'Italian': [8.5, 7.5, 6.0]}
```

Finally we can replace each dictionary element with its mean:

```py
for country in all_data:
    values = all_data[country]
    mean = sum(values)/float(len(values))
    # replace the list with the mean value
    all_data[country] = mean
```

Which should produce what you need:

```
In [147]: all_data
Out[147]: {'American': 4.25, 'German': 6.375, 'Italian': 7.333333333333333}
```

If you require the result to two decimal points, you can also convert it into a string using c-style formatting: `'%.2f'%mean`

Comment: This really helps me visualize what's happening. Very clarifying. Thank you!

Comment: Please don't give away the answer to a no-effort homework question. This is a missed learning opportunity.

Answer (score -1):

In order to compute any statistic, you should create a sample of data. In this case, you may build a dictionary of samples for each country food. In Python, `defaultdict` has a big advantage that you don't need check if a key is in `dict`. After then, you can get a new dictionary with calculated mean.

Code example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for record in food.values():
    d[record[1]].append(record[-1])

average = {k: mean(v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Comment: Please don't give away the answer to a no-effort homework question. This is a missed learning opportunity.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica it's fine to give an answer but they should help understand how to do similar questions in the future.